# How to include "from" day in bizdays() in R

Tags: r, date, time, data-science, bizdays

Let's say I do the following:

```
create.calendar(name='MyCalendar', weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'),
            adjust.from=adjust.next, adjust.to=adjust.previous)
bizdays.options$set(default.calendar='MyCalendar')
```

Now, I want to calculate the number of business days between 2020-11-23 and 2020-11-27 (including November 23rd and 27th).

However, when I use `bizdays()`:

```
bizdays("2020-11-23", "2020-11-27")
```

The output is "4". I would like to get a "5" to include all days. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to include `from` only if it's a business day i.e `is.bizday(from)==TRUE` thus we can make up the following function:

```r
library(bizdays)
bizdays_inc <- function (from, to, cal = bizdays.options$get("default.calendar")) 
{
    is.bizday(from) + bizdays(from, to, cal)
}
bizdays_inc("2020-11-23", "2020-11-27")
[1] 5
```

Or if we set the financial flag to `FALSE` in the calendar:

```r
create.calendar(name='MyCalendar', weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'),
            adjust.from=adjust.next, adjust.to=adjust.previous, financial=F)
bizdays.options$set(default.calendar='MyCalendar')

bizdays("2020-11-23", "2020-11-27")
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be useful. However, is there any other way of achieving this by using the bizdays package instead of creating a custom function?

Comment: @caproki this uses the bizdays package.

Comment: I meant by using it directly. But it's ok

Comment: @caproki tbh I looked in the bizdays code you need to set the financial flag in the calendar to `FALSE`, check my edit